# How to back to reveal view controller after perform segue a view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I use **Reveal View Controller** in Swift 3. When in my **"sw_front"** tagged *mymainpageViewController* I use perform segue a *View Controller*. When I want to back its nothing working. (perform segue or reveal view controller push controller..) How can I back to *mymainpageViewController*?

Comment: always put your efforts

Comment: What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use this  code in your Second View Controller from where you want to go back:

If you want to go back to the previous view controller

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

If you want to go back to the root view controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```